# Use defined resource to populate template file

Tags: puppet

I am working on making our puppet infrastructure more dynamic where I can add any number of nodes and these will automatically be applied in another nodes configuration.

An example:
I have X number of hosts running a Java application, which are defined by our **javaapp** module with the following define in it (simplified):

```
define javaapp::site (
  $site_name,
  $site_port ) {
  # Doing some stuff regarding deployment, service management etc here
}
```

These are defined in the site.pp file like this:

```
javaapp::site { 'app01':
  play_site_name    => 'app01',
  play_site_port    => 9100,
}
```

We have a nginx reverse proxy in front of these application servers where I need to forward requests to a range of servers. Currently my nginx template looks like this:

```
upstream app-hosts {
  server <%= @host_app_01 %>:9100;
  server <%= @host_app_02 %>:9100;
}
```

Where @host_app_01 and @host_app_02 have been defined globally in the site.pp file

What I would like to do is to collect an array of the nodes with a specific javaapp site name and use it in the nginx template. Something like this pseudo-code:

```
upstream app-hosts {
  <% @host_app.each do |host| %>
    server <%= @host.ip %>:<%= @host.appPort %>;
  <% end %>
}
```

I have read a little about exported resources, but I can't figure out whether it is the right thing for this situation?

Is it even possible to do with puppet?

We are running puppet version 3.7.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exported resources are a very adequate design pattern for this, yes. However, a template cannot directly use the resources (imported or otherwise) from the current catalog.

Your best call will be one of the [concat](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/concat) modules. Have your defined types export concat snippets for your applications. Instead of a `file` that uses a template for its `content`, use a `concat` resource.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the concat modules - didn't realize that was an option until now. I also noticed that jfryman's nginx module actually supports exported resources, so maybe I should just go with that in the future when I finish converting my sites to his module